# FCM token or APNS token isn't working for Firebase notification on iOS

Tags: ios, firebase, xamarin.ios, firebase-cloud-messaging, apple-push-notifications

I need to register FCM token to APNS which I have tried using below configurations and methods.
I have configured firebase properly sent test messages to all the users and it works fine.
but when I try to get installation id, either it doesn't give me the id or received id doesn't work.
I have tried to use **APNS token, FCM token and Device token** (object of **NSData**) in **RegisteredForRemoteNotifications** method which is received in the parameter and also added **DidReceiveRegistrationToken** method.
I also tried mapping APNS token with above 2 tokens but didn't work.
I also tried to enable and disable **Swizzling**.

```
Messaging.SharedInstance.ApnsToken = DeviceToken;
Messaging.SharedInstance.ApnsToken = Messaging.SharedInstance.FcmToken;
```

Note - I am using Xamarin forms iOS for the app.
I am using below page for configurations:
I have followed steps mentioned in below page for configurations:

https://github.com/xamarin/GoogleApisForiOSComponents/blob/master/docs/Firebase/CloudMessaging/GettingStarted.md#firebase-cloud-messaging-on-ios